# Getting a keyError: 0 with the linear classifier code

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying the make a linear classifier code without using the APIs to understand the fundamentals. Below is the code:

```
    import numpy as np 
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    import pandas as pd 
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    
    data = pd.read_csv('files/weather.csv', parse_dates= True, index_col=0)
    data.head()
    
    data.isnull().sum()
    
    dataset = data[['Humidity3pm','Pressure3pm','RainTomorrow']].dropna()
    
    X = dataset[['Humidity3pm', 'Pressure3pm']]
    y = dataset['RainTomorrow']
    y = np.array([0 if value == 'No' else 1 for value in y])
    
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)
    
    
    def linear_classifier(X, y, learning_rate=0.01, num_epochs=100):
        num_features = X.shape[1] 
        weights = np.zeros(num_features)
        bias = 0
        
        for epoch in range(num_epochs):
            for i in range(X.shape[0]):
                linear_output = np.dot(X[i], weights) + bias
               
                y_pred = np.sign(linear_output)
                
               
                error = y[i] - y_pred
                # print("The value of error=", error)
                weights = weights + learning_rate * error * X[i]
    
                bias += learning_rate * error
                
        return weights, bias
    
    
    weights, bias = linear_classifier(X_train, y_train)   ## This lines gives the error
```

> I am quite new to python and getting the error:

```
    Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    File c:\Users\manuc\anaconda3\envs\learning_python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3802, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
       3801 try:
    -> 3802     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
       3803 except KeyError as err:
    
            
    KeyError: 0
```

I would be great help if I can helped in resolving this error. I am new to python and machine learning. Thank you in adavance.

**Edit**
Edited the question to provide complete error.

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\Users\manuc\anaconda3\envs\learning_python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3802, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3801 try:
-> 3802     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803 except KeyError as err:

File c:\Users\manuc\anaconda3\envs\learning_python\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File c:\Users\manuc\anaconda3\envs\learning_python\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:165, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5745, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5753, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[170], line 1
----> 1 weights, bias = linear_classifier(X_train, y_train) 

Cell In[169], line 10, in linear_classifier(X, y, learning_rate, num_epochs)
      8 for epoch in range(num_epochs):
...
   3807     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3808     #  the TypeError.
   3809     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 0
```

The link from where I have taken the weather data : https://github.com/LearnPythonWithRune/MachineLearningWithPython/blob/main/jupyter/final/files/weather.csv

Comment: You need to provide the full error output instead of the snippet you shared. Also, looking at your code it is likely that the line `linear_output = np.dot(X[i], weights) + bias` raises the exception because there is key `0` in `X`. According to the documentation for `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` it looks like in version `0.16` if your data is not sparse then the return type is the same as the input type. In your case, that would be a Pandas Dataframe. Perhaps, it would be useful to convert that into an array of tuples.

Comment: Thank you @ShahanM for your response. I have edited the question to include the complete error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full error log includes the following lines

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "linear_classifier.py", line 40, in <module>
    weights, bias = linear_classifier(X_train, y_train)
  File "linear_classifier.py", line 27, in linear_classifier
    linear_output = np.dot(X[i], weights) + bias
```

As you can see, the error is in indexing `X[i]`. You will notice that `X_train` is a Dataframe with a date-based index and not an integer index.

This can be solved by changing line 13 of your code from `X = dataset[['Humidity3pm', 'Pressure3pm']]` to

```
...
X = dataset[['Humidity3pm', 'Pressure3pm']].values
...
```

Adding the values at the end returns only the values as a `numpy.ndarray` [[Link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html)]